# Swapping lower byte (0-7) with the higher one (8-15) one

Tags: c++, c

I now know how it's done in one line, altough I fail to realise why my first draft doesn't work aswell. What I'm trying to do is saving the lower part into a different variable, shifting the higher byte to the right and adding the two numbers via OR. However, it just cuts the lower half of the hexadecimal and returns the rest.

```
short int method(short int number) {


short int a = 0;
for (int x = 8; x < 16; x++){
    if ((number & (1 << x)) == 1){
        a = a | (1<<x);
    }
}

    number = number >> 8;

short int solution = number | a;
return solution;
```

Comment: Beware shifting a signed variable: the sign bit can cause Undefined Behaviour. Better to use unsigned, or cast to unsigned before the shift.

Comment: You're doing a right shift of a signed (short) int - this results in implementation-defined behaviour (usually an arithmetic shift). Use unsigned (short) ints to avoid this problem.

Comment: Trace through this in a debugger, stepping one instruction at a time, and examining the values of each variable.

Comment: `(number & (1 << x)) == 1)` can only be true when `x == 0`.

Comment: Also, you're shifting x over N places and and'ing it with number - if that bit is set, what will the result be? What are you comparing it to? Is 0010b & (0001b << 1) == 1?

Comment: @Walter: That's what I thought?

Comment: Try it, print out the result.

Comment: @Weather where exactly would I need to cast?

Comment: Borrowing from @dasblinkenlight answer: `return (short)(((unsigned short)number << 8) | ((unsigned short)number >> 8));`

Comment: @Walter but I wanted to "move" the 1 to the position where I wanted to check if the bit is set and not to shift a second number by 1?
also, whats the placehold for a binary number

this doesnt work `printf("%d & (%d << 1)",0010b,0001b);`

Comment: @taclight there isn't one, you would print the result of the operation using decimals. printf("%u\n", a & ( 1 <<  b )), where a is an unsigned integer type.

Comment: @walter well it now just prints the same thing I typed in. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: also, if I use `(x & (1<<3))` on 0100, will it check for the position at which the 1 is located or does it count from position 0?

Comment: @taclight I'm not sure what you mean, but 4 & ( 1 << 3) => 0100b & 0100b = 0100b. The and operation a & b = c sets the bits in c to 1 iff the corresponding bit in a and b were set to one. So in your example, you're checking if the nth bit is set. The result of your and won't equal one though, it'll equal 2^n (if that bit is set). So in the example at the start of this comment, you shift left n=3, if the 2^3 bit is set, the result will be 2^n. It is, so the result is 2^n, or 4. In your example, you see if it's equal to one, which as others have mentioned will only be true when n=0

Comment: @Walter yeah I got it now, I also fixed a few mistakes my programm got that I did not see hours after hours, thank you very much for your patience - code works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if ((number & (1 << x)) == 1)`

This is only going to return true if `x` is 0.  Since 1 in binary is `00000000 00000001`, and `1 << x` is going to set all but the x'th bit to 0.

You don't care if it's 1 or not, you just care if it's non-zero.  Use

`if (number & (1 << x))`

Comment: If the bit is set, what would this statement "return"?

Comment: `number & (1 << 8)` either returns `00000000 00000000` or `00000001 00000000` depending on whether the 8th bit is set.  `number & (1 << 9)` either returns `00000000 00000000` or `00000010 00000000` depending on whether the 9th bit is set.  `number & (1 << 10)` either returns `00000000 00000000` or `00000100 00000000` depending on whether the 10th bit is set, &ct &ct.

Comment: So, it's not returning 1 in any case.

Comment: so our code checks for anything but 0 and if so, it executes the instruction?  
Is it because we have no boolean? Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes.  `if(x)` is a numerical test that evaluates true iff x != 0.  In a lot of cases (like your question) it's really useful because it allows us to pretend that the `&` operator is a boolean operation.

Comment: The moral of the story is that true does not mean 1 in C.

Answer (score 8):

You are doing it one bit at a time; a better approach would do it with a single operation:

```
uint16_t method(uint16_t number) {
    return (number << 8) | (number >> 8);
}
```

The code above specifies 16-bit unsigned type explicitly, thus avoiding issues related to sign extension. You need to include `<stdint.h>` (or `<cstdint>` in C++) in order for this to compile.